# UMP of a Beta($\theta,1$) distribution

Tags: statistics

I need to find the UMP of a BETA$(\theta,1)$ distribution. I know that the pdf of this problem is
$$f(x;\theta)=\theta x^{\theta-1}=\theta e^{(\theta-1)\log{x}}$$
Thereby this family contains a MLR for $\sum_{i=1}^n\log{x_i}$. This is were i get stuck. How do i have to proceed to find the UMP? Extra information: it's the UMP, size $\alpha$, test for $H_0:\theta_0\leq1$ versus $H_a:\theta>1$.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

[One knows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_most_powerful_test) that the UMP test of size $\alpha$ of $H_0:\theta\lt\theta_0$ vs $H_1:\theta\gt\theta_0$ is $\phi(x)=\mathbf 1_{x\gt x_0}$ where $x_0$ solves $P_{\theta_0}[X\gt x_0]=\alpha$. Here, $P_{\theta}[X\gt x]=1-x^\theta$ hence $x_0=(1-\alpha)^{1/\theta_0}$. For $\theta_0=1$,  this shows that the UMP test of size $\alpha$ of $H_0:\theta\lt1$ vs $H_1:\theta\gt1$ is $\phi(x)=\mathbf 1_{x\gt1-\alpha}$.